# Changing Robot Framework to use Python 3.x On Mac

Tags: python, macos, unix, robotframework

I have an issue where i have updated my python and set the pythonpath to python3.x directory, I can execute commands like pip install robotframework, this uses the python3.x version

If i do `echo $PYTHONPATH`

i get

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin/python3
```

but if i try to execute a robot test using a simple command It says that the pythonpath is different

Robot Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  /usr/local/bin
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

Comment: what is this "simple command"?

Comment: robot test.robot

Comment: Try ``python3 -m robot.run tests.robot`` or ``python3 -m robot tests.robot``.

Comment: that works but its there a way to get rid of python3 -m and using robot as python3 default?

Comment: try to install RF for python 3 with ``pip3 install robotframework``

Comment: Everything is installed on both python2 and python3, and i have change the defualt python path to point to python3 , but somehow robot command still uses python2, if i uninstall robot from python2 then i get 'robot' command not found

Comment: where does ``which robot`` point to? If it's a script, change the path to the python executable in it.

Comment: What does `python -V` return?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a virtual environment based on python3.x. From there, activate such environment, install dependencies, and you can simply use `python` instead of `python3.x`.

Note that, you have to make sure you don't have installed robotframework packages in you default python installation `/usr/local/bin` or they will be used instead, which is what it looks like is happening from your example.